# Fast Way to find a specific Object.Name String in an Array VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

I got an Array with Objects. These Objects have one property called "Name". You can of course read it out via Object.Name :) . I am now looking for a fast way to find the index of an Object with a specified name.

I need too do this about 30000 times, so it needs to be a fast way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should help you :

```
Function Get_Index_From_Name(anArray As Variant, ObjectName As String)
Dim i As Long

For i = LBound(anArray) To UBound(anArray)
    If anArray(i).Name <> ObjectName Then
    Else
        Get_Index_From_Name = i
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do this is by creating additional module-level object of `Scripting.Dictionary` class that will be used to map names of items with their index.

At the first glance it can seem to be the waste of time and memory, because additional object is required and it need to be populated with the data that already exist in the array. But for very high number of iterations (and you said that you need to do this about 30000 times) this cost is quickly surpassed by the gains we have from using dictionary.

Below is an example presenting this attitude:

```
Option Explicit

'This must be module-level variable.
Dim indexMap As Object


Public Sub test()
    Const COUNTER As Long = 5000
    Const ITERATIONS As Long = 1000000
    '-------------------------------------------------------
    Dim items() As Object
    Dim startTime As Double
    Dim name As String
    Dim index As Long
    Dim i As Long
    '-------------------------------------------------------

    'Create an array of items for test.
    items = createArrayForTest(COUNTER)


    'Get the current timestamp to check how long it took.
    startTime = VBA.Timer

    'Create a dictionary that will be used as a map index-itemName.
    Set indexMap = createIndexMap(items)

    'Actual test
    For i = 1 To ITERATIONS

        'Create some random name for which the function will find its index.
        name = "item_" & VBA.Int(VBA.Rnd * 1000)
        index = findIndex(name)

    Next i


    Debug.Print COUNTER & " items | " & _
                ITERATIONS & " iterations | " & _
                "Time: " & Format(VBA.Timer - startTime, "#.##") & "s"


End Sub



Private Function createArrayForTest(COUNTER As Long) As Object()
    Dim arr() As Object
    Dim item As Obj
    Dim i As Long
    '-------------------------------------------------------

    ReDim arr(1 To COUNTER)

    For i = 1 To COUNTER
        Set item = New Obj
        item.name = "item_" & i
        Set arr(i) = item
    Next i

    createArrayForTest = arr

End Function


Private Function createIndexMap(items() As Object) As Object
    Dim i As Long
    '-------------------------------------------------------

    'Create dictionary and populate it with the items from the given array.
    'The name of each item is the key, and the index of this item is the value.
    Set createIndexMap = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With createIndexMap
        For i = LBound(items) To UBound(items)
            Call .Add(items(i).name, i)
        Next i
    End With

End Function


Public Function findIndex(name As String) As Long

    With indexMap
        If .exists(name) Then
            findIndex = .item(name)
        Else
            'If there is no item with such name, the function
            'returns -1.
            findIndex = -1
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

I made some tests for various combinations of number of items in base array and number of indexes to be found. Below are the results:

```
5000 items | 1000000 iterations | Time: 4,59s
10000 items | 100000 iterations | Time: 0,52s
30000 items | 100000 iterations | Time: 0,85s
30000 items | 1000000 iterations | Time: 7,41s
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this will work great, but this time I take R3uk's Variant for the ease